# what does $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'; mean in Codeigniter Router

Tags: codeigniter

In documentation of Codeigniter https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

I could not get what does `$1` mean in expression  `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`

Comment: You use braces to catch a matching result, every pair of braces have a number so if you have (something)(another) the first pair is $1, the other is $2 and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$1` would be whatever matched by `(:any)` group - which is, really,  anything. Whatever you add will get passed as the parameter for `view` method in `pages` controller.

More here on [routing with codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 25):

`$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` 
means that anything you type on the url will proceed to `pages/view/$1` the `$1` here is the parameter you would like to pass to a controller/method example

`$route['login/(:any)'] = 'home/bacon/$1';`

in this example you are telling CI that anything that goes to `login` with any parameter like `login/john` will proceed to your `home/bacon/john` `(:any)` will match all string and integer
if you use `(:num)` it will only match integer parameters like

`$route['login/(':num')'] = 'home/bacon/$1'`

in this config you are specifying that if a url `login` has a integer after it like `login/1234`, you would like it to redirect to `home/bacon/1234` if you don't know how many parameters you would like to pass you could try
`$route['login/(:any).*'] = 'home/bacon/$1'` 
more on this could be read at 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html